# Fetching applicationDefault from GoogleCredentials

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I am working on a java spring project which requires me to publish a message to Google Pub/Sub. I need to send the access token as an Authorization header in the post request.
I tried using GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault() but it requires GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to be set in the environmental variables.

Here is what I tried

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
Field field = env.getClass().getDeclaredField("m");
field.setAccessible(true);

((Map<String, String>) field.get(env)).put("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "/etc/gcp/sa_credentials.json");

GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
credentials.refreshIfExpired();

String accessToken = credentials.getAccessToken().toString();
```

When I try to run this, I get this error -
`java.io.IOException: Scopes not configured for service account. Scoped should be specified by calling createScoped or passing scopes to constructor`

I am not sure how to add scope for the service account. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a scoped credential like this

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
```